# How to book hotels as an unmarried couple in Dubai?

Tags: hotels, dubai

Hi my girlfriend works in Dubai and i ll be traveling there, so can i stay with her in a hotel? also can any one suggest good hotel to stay in dubai?

Answer (score 5):

You can share the same room as your girlfriend in Dubai. This is absolutely not an issue there. The hotels would have really hard time to be profitable if non married couple weren't allowed to check-in. This is critical for a tourist destination to be able to attract couples regardless of their status.

Not everybody can book two rooms, especially in Dubai where hotels tend to be expensive...

The only recommendation is to be respectful with your attire and behaviours (ie for instance, don't kiss your girlfriend on the mouth in public areas).

Then for hotels, here is a list depending on your criteria :

Budget/cheap hotels (less than 50 $/night during low season) :

- Downtown, near Burj Khalifa and Dubai Mall : [Rove Downtown
  Dubai](http://www.rovehotels.com/)
- Near Dubai Marina : [Pearl Marina Hotel Appartments](http://www.pearlmarinahotel.com/)

Business type, a bit more expensive (less than 100 $/night during low season) :

- Near Burj Khalifa and Dubai Mall : [Dusit Thani](http://www.dusit.com/dusitthani/dubai/)
- Near Mall of Emirates : Donatello Hotel

Holidays style, beach side, upscale (less than 300 $/night during low season)

- Next to the Palm : [One&Only Royal Mirage](http://www.olielo.com/hotel-review/oneonly-royal-mirage-dubai-deluxe-room/) (this is my favourite, get there for a lunch at least!)
- On Palm Jumeirah : [Jumeirah Zabeel Saray](http://www.olielo.com/hotel-review/jumeirah-zabeel-saray-dubai-junior-suite/) (this one also has nice restaurants)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, i just looking for a downtown hotel to stay with my girlfriend , because i have already booked packages so i ll be out  most of the time

Comment: And what is your budget? Are you looking for cheap/casual or high-end/more luxury hotels?

Comment: i m looking for casual kind

Comment: Ok edited the answer to add some reco!